# Can Google Apps Script read the contents of a public folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

If there's a folder on someone's Drive with sharing set so anyone with the link can view it, can a Google Apps Script see its contents? That is:

```
DocsList.getFolderByID(id).getFiles()
```

will show me the contents of a folder on my (or the user's) Drive. But is there a similar method for viewing files in a publicly shared folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If by "public folder" you mean "a folder in another user's Google Drive that has been shared as public", then the answer is yes.

Nothing special - just use the ID of the folder as you would your own. There are some methods that you will not be able to use, for example `Document.getOwner()` will complain about permissions.